# How to fill out an ArrayList with for each loop? (Java)

Tags: java

I have to fill in an ArrayList with the first 10 multiples of two using a for each loop. I really can't seem to figure out how and I can't use any other loops.

Here is my code which is not working.

```
   ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);  
   for (Integer y : arraylist) {
         arraylist.add( (2+(y*2)));      
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to use a 'for each' loop instead of a regular 'for' loop?

Comment: Can you create the List like this?  List<Integer> arraylist = (List<Integer> )Arrays.asList(new Integer[10]);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simple

```
final int[] numbers = new int[] {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int number : numbers) {
    list.add(number);
}
```

Comment: This does actually fit all the specs.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this maybe?

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).map(y -> 2 + y * 2).forEach(arraylist::add);
```

Comment: Too lambdish. The student is beginner in Computer Science :)). Don't freak him out

Comment: @nucandrei Can't think of anything else that would include a for-each loop :D

Comment: @nucandrei:  I like this solution anyway.  It's not just a beginner student that's going to look at this answer.

Comment: @Bubletan See my answer. It does what you wrote but without using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop loops over all values in `arrayList` since it's empty, the part in the loop is actually never running. Use

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
     arrayList.add(2 * (i + 1));
```

instead

Comment: @jHilscher well foreach loop on a empty collection will never execute.

Comment: i'd be really cursious how op is gonna use a for-each loop on an empty arraylist...

Comment: @Paul It only works if you use a separate non-empty collection to foreach against.  Like making an array of 10 `y` values then using a foreach against the other collection to fill this one.

Comment: i know, but in that case you'd first have to create the array or whatever you use. and thats the point where you wind up with the same problem as before.

Comment: @Paul yep.  Unless you make that a hard-coded array or something.

Comment: @Paul why do you think that op should use the for each loop on that list? This is obviously wrong, but that doesn't mean that this assignment could use a 'regular' for loop instead. The task is currently unclear.

Answer (score 3):

I'll address the point that everyone here is mostly glossing over:  there is a key difference between a normal `for` statement and the enhanced-`for` statement.

The enhanced-`for` is defined [in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) as syntactic sugar.  What *kind* of sugar you get depends on what you're iterating over.

- If you're iterating over an `Iterable` like an `ArrayList`, it is using the `Iterator` from that entity.

  ```
  for(I #i=Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext();){
      VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier=
      (TargetType) #i.next();
      Statement
  }
  ```
- If you're iterating over an array, then it's shorthand for the common `for` statements one is accustomed to doing.

  ```
  T[] #a = Expression;
  L1: L2: ... Lm:
  for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
      VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
      Statement
  }
  ```

Thus, the enhanced-`for` has one assumption:

### What you're iterating over must be a non-empty collection or array.

The statement is only meant to iterate over *existing* elements, not provide a way or interface to iteratively add new elements.

There are any number of ways to sort this out, but the simplest is the most common approach:  use a `for` statement.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);  
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arraylist.add( (2+(i*2)));      
}
```

Comment: D'oh! "What you're iterating over must be a non-empty collection or array." Thank you, I resembled that comment until I read your answer, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `ArrayList` with 10 as constructor parameters, which define it initial capacity (which is already 10 by default btw), but does not set any value. In other words, you try to iterate on an empty list, hence never enter it.

You can't achieve this with a `for-each`, you could achieve this with a `for`.

```
final List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
   myList.add(2 * i);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
int[] values = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
for (int i : values) { list.add(i * 2); }
```

(stolen from a comment! :) )

Answer (score 1):

Unlike arrays, ArrayList won't be initialized with objects. So the size of the ArrayList will be zero after the initialization. One work around is to create the list from Arrays as below: (But this is only a work around). But even in this case, the List will be initialized with nulls, not with 0s. So the y will be null.

```
List<Integer> arraylist = Arrays.asList(new Integer[10]);
        //Collections.fill(arraylist, new Integer(1));
        System.out.println(arraylist);
        int i=0;
        for (Integer y : arraylist) {
             //System.out.println( (2+(y*2)));
             arraylist.set(i++, ((i*2)));      
       }
```

Comment: Good idea to comment the line `System.out.println( (2+(y*2)));`, because it would cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Unlike Integer[], int[] will initialize with 0. But there is no auto boxing supported between int[] to integer[]

Comment: @Tom, Yes you are right, my comment was not the response for your comment. My comment was about why can't I use int[].

Comment: Oh ok. Then we don't need my second comment anymore :).